# Trigger alter and create table SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers, ddl-trigger

I would like to feed a table with all the updates and alters of tables in my database.
For example: if I add a column called `testColumn` in the table `Test` my table would have something like this:

```
TABLE    COLUMN         DATE
Test     testColumn     2014-05-05 05:25:31
```

I tried this using `sys.tables` and `sys.columns` but it doesn't work

Someone can help me?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? What have you tried thus far?

Comment: Do you need the datetime, at which the a new column has been added to the table?